# Django Rest Framework: PUT/POST fails in case of blank optional fields in nested serializer

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I am using Django ver 1.7 and Django Rest Framework ver 3.1.3.

I have two models that are inter-related as follows:

```
class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)     
    GENDER_CHOICES = (
        ('M', 'Male'),
        ('F', 'Female'),
        ('T', 'Transgender'),
    )
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=GENDER_CHOICES)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
    work_phone = models.CharField(max_length=15, blank=True, null=True,
                        validators=[RegexValidator(regex='^[0-9]+$', 
                        message='Phone number must contain only digits', 
                        code='nomatch')])
    home_phone = models.CharField(max_length=15, blank=True, null=True,
                        validators=[RegexValidator(regex='^[0-9]+$', 
                        message='Phone number must contain only digits', 
                        code='nomatch')])
    mobile = models.CharField(max_length=15, blank=True, null=True,
                        validators=[RegexValidator(regex='^[0-9]+$', 
                        message='Phone number must contain only digits', 
                        code='nomatch')])
    email = models.EmailField(blank=True)
    date_of_birth = models.DateField()
    user = OneToOneField(User, null=True, blank=True)   
    DOCUMENT_CHOICES = (
        ('DL', 'Driving License'),
        ('RC', 'Ration card'),
        ('PP', 'Passport'),
        ('NO',  'None'),                 
    )
    additional_document = models.CharField(max_length=2, choices=DOCUMENT_CHOICES)
    document_number = models.CharField(max_length=10, blank=True, null=True)
    document_scan = models.FileField(max_length=1000, blank=True, null=True)
    photo = models.ImageField(blank=True,null=True)

class Admin(models.Model):
    person = OneToOneField(Person)
    # More fields will be added later
```

So Person contains a OneToOne field pointing to User (Django's auth_user model) and Admin has a OneToOne field pointing to Person. However, I would like to provide the end-user with a single screen to update all these details in one shot (similar to combining multiple ModelForms in one template).

I've created explicit serializers corresponding to each of these models and they have a nested relationship as follows.

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    id = serializers.IntegerField(label='ID', read_only=True)
    username = serializers.CharField(max_length=30)
    password = serializers.CharField(max_length=128, style={'input_type': 'password'})

class PersonSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    id = serializers.IntegerField(label="ID", read_only=True)
    user = UserSerializer()
    name = serializers.CharField(max_length=200)
    gender = serializers.ChoiceField(choices=['M', 'F', 'T'])
    address = serializers.CharField(max_length=1000)
    work_phone = serializers.CharField(max_length=15, required=False, allow_null=True)
    home_phone = serializers.CharField(max_length=15, required=False, allow_null=True)
    mobile = serializers.CharField(max_length=15, required=False, allow_null=True)
    email = serializers.EmailField(required=False, allow_blank=True)
    date_of_birth = serializers.DateField()
    additional_document = serializers.ChoiceField(choices=['NO','DL', 'RC', 'PP'])
    document_number = serializers.CharField(max_length=10, required=False, allow_null=True)
    document_scan = serializers.FileField(max_length=1000, required=False, allow_null=True)
    photo = serializers.ImageField(required=False, allow_null=True)


class AdminSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    id = serializers.IntegerField(label="ID", read_only=True)
    person = PersonSerializer()
    # More fields will be added later
```

Each of the serializers has an explicit create() and update() method defined, which I've omitted for the sake of brevity. I can see that these are not getting invoked, so the error is probably encountered during validation itself.

When I perform a GET operation, the Person or Admin api endpoint returns all the nested objects correctly.

When I perform a PUT or POST operation on Person, it accepts blank inputs in the optional fields. However, if I keep the same fields as blank when performing a PUT or POST operation on the Admin object, it flags errors as follows.

My PUT request is:

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "person": {
        "id": 1,
        "user": {
            "id": 2,
            "username": "nina.sinha",
            "password": "pbkdf2_sha256$12000$CjmifxpP1DDv$1622S7enIwnT+NcwhMKIEWrq8Uy7gQQJPQQueML21Sg="
        },
        "name": "Nina Sinha",
        "gender": "F",
        "address": "1234, 6th Cross, 7th Main Street",
        "work_phone": "42011567",
        "home_phone": "",
        "mobile": "9854609658",
        "email": "nina.sinha@yahoo.com",
        "date_of_birth": "1985-04-03",
        "additional_document": "NO",
        "document_number": "",
        "document_scan": null,
        "photo": null
    }
}
```

Errors:

```
HTTP 400 Bad Request
Content-Type: application/json
Vary: Accept
Allow: GET, PUT, PATCH, HEAD, OPTIONS

{
    "person": {
        "document_scan": [
            "The submitted data was not a file. Check the encoding type on the form."
        ],
        "photo": [
            "The submitted data was not a file. Check the encoding type on the form."
        ],
        "document_number": [
            "This field may not be blank."
        ],
        "user": [
            "This field is required."
        ],
        "home_phone": [
            "This field may not be blank."
        ]
    }
}
```

The fields document_scan, document_number and home_phone were left blank, but they are optional fields and the AdminSerializer should accept this.

The user related fields HAD been entered but I still get the error "This field is required" as if they are missing.

What am I missing here? I face the same issue if I use ModelSerializers.

Comment: Can you put the post request you are trying to send?

Comment: Edited inline to add the contents of PUT request.

Answer (score 0):

Looking your code why don't you use modelserializers instead of serializer. In serializer level you can change the fields according to the requirements. You can change the required field to non-required fields in serializer and it won't be problem on model level.

serializers.py

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('id', 'username', 'password')

class PersonSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    user = UserSerializer()
    class Meta:
        model = Person
        fields = ('id', 'user', # specify other fields)

class AdminSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    person = PersonSerializer()
    class Meta:
        model = Admin
        fields = ('id', 'person', # specify other fields)
```

If you want to change the user field to non-required in PersonSerializer change the code as follows.

```
user = UserSerializer(required=False)
```

Comment: I had faced the same issue even with ModelSerializers. A two-level nesting worked fine, but a three-level nesting threw up errors complaining that fields were missing, even though I had included them, OR the field was optional. I've worked around the problem now by having a two-level nesting of AdminSerializer including PersonSerializer, and keeping user as a serializers.SlugRelatedField inside PersonSerializer. That seems to do the trick.